# CHtmlEditCtrl: Windows is destroyed on ShowWindow(SW_HIDE)

Tags: c++, mfc, activex, webbrowser-control

I've derived CHtmlEditCtrl, and done very few changes on it. I haven't overriden any methods so far.

The problem is, when I call ShowWindow(SW_HIDE) on this control, the window itself gets destroyed (m_hWnd is NULL). Since CHtmlEditCtrl is a wrapper for ActiveX Control, I recon that when I hide the control, the ActiveX object gets released.

Is there a way to hide this control without a call to ShowWindow, or maybe a way to prevent the window from being destroyed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a known bug: [BUG: WebBrowser Control Destroyed When Hidden](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182111).

Workaround:

```
::ShowWindow(m_ctlEditHtml.GetSafeHwnd(), SW_HIDE);             
::ShowWindow(m_ctlEditHtml.GetSafeHwnd(), SW_SHOW);
```

Comment: This is why I love Stackoverflow; people who know what are they talking about.